# JNDI not working in JUnit after upgrading Wicket from 6.20 to 7.0

Tags: junit, jetty, wicket, embedded-jetty

I decided to upgrade a recent Wicket project from 6.20 to 7.0. This was quite smooth for the main code, but I had a problem with the setup code for JNDI in the JUnit environment. I am using :

```java
try {                                                   
    // create and bind JNDI resource for database connection

    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

    ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");
    ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env/jdbc");

    SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myProject;userName=myUser;password=myPassword");

    ic.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyProject", ds);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This worked fine with Wicket 6.20, but throws a `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException` on the call to createSubcontext().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fruitless experimentation, the key information was in http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-embedded.html.

With the change from Jetty 7 to Jetty 9 between Wicket 6.20 and 7.0, a jetty-all-server jar is no longer available, so the wicket-quickstart-archetype depends on the individual jars. To these it's necessary to add a dependency to jetty-plus (which in turn loads jetty-jndi) in the project's pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```